# admob in Android (phonegap) on click redirects market app. but shows white screen on back key press.

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I am using admob to display ad in my android app with Phonegap(Corodoa).
when user clicks on ad app redirects user to market app(as link in ad is for market app)
when user wants to come back to my app **By Pressing Back Key a white screen** comes(should be web browser).

after pressing back key again it goes to my App.
My question is why white screen comes and how can avoid it to come?

Answer (score 1):

That is an issue with the specific ad that you saw.  The advertiser made a click-through URL to a web address that then redirects the user to the play store, instead of just making the click through URL a play store URI.

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do to fix this.